# Turning off "created by" stamp when generating files in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I can't find an option for this. For example, when I create a new Scala class, this text is placed in the file:

```
/**
 * Created by ben on 6/23/14.
 */
```

Answer (score 173, accepted):

In IntelliJ 13 and above it is in the `File and Code Templates` area of the settings dialog. In Idea 15+ you can get there by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on windows or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on osx and then typing `Include Templates` in the popup action search dialog. There should be a tab called `Includes` on which you will find the Java and ActionScript file types, and the text can simply be removed completely if you like.

But, in more recent versions of IntelliJ things have got quite a bit easier. The first time it generates this stuff, put your cursor in the generated comments and hit <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd> (or the equivalent according to your key-mapping preferences) to bring up the 'fix' options, and select 'edit template'. This will bring you right to the setting that needs to be updated. Simply remove all the text (or replace it with something more palatable to you), hit <kbd>enter</kbd> and you're done.

Answer (score 36):

In case, someone wondering about how to add the creation info when it's somehow missed (like in my case),

[image]

Comment: Here is the IntelliJ documentation for adding variables: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-template-variables.html

Comment: Thanks! the picture speaks more than words.

Answer (score 25):

In Intellij 14 it is in the File and Code Templates area of the settings dialog. There should be a tab called Includes and File Header in it. Remove all text on the right side.

Answer (score 6):

The keyboard shortcuts provided in the other answers did not work for me.
You need to go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates
If you want to change the header you need to go to "Includes" tab

[The official docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html)

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot

Answer (score 6):

In case you want to remove all comments which have already been created. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the *Replace in path* dialog. Check the Regex option and replace

```
/\*\*\n \* Created by .*\n \*/
```

with *nothing*.