# Turning off "created by" header when generating files in CLion

Tags: clion

When you create file in CLion, the following header is placed in the top of file:

```
//
// Created by <username> on 14.01.18.
//
```

Someone [can remove this header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24370502/5812238) by go to `Settings` → `Editor` → `File and Code Templates` → `Includes` → `C File Header`. There will be text:

```
#if ($HEADER_COMMENTS)
//
// Created by $USER_NAME on ${DATE}.
#if ($ORGANIZATION_NAME && $ORGANIZATION_NAME != "")
// Copyright (c) $YEAR ${ORGANIZATION_NAME}#if (!$ORGANIZATION_NAME.endsWith(".")).#end All rights reserved.
#end
//
#end
```

**I can delete this text and header will be removed**. But looks like if I set `$HEADER_COMMENTS` variable to `false` then header will be removed too. So my question is:

What is `$HEADER_COMMENTS` variable and how can I change it?

Comment: Related bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-2819

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html

Apparently the variable `${HEADER_COMMENTS}` is [always true and used for testing purposes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/file-template-variables.html#predefined_template_variables), so you can't influence it.

Answer (score 11):

I found this post at when searching to do the same thing. I didn't want to delete the whole thing as I'm using CLion for college and I might have a use for a template but I don't like the current one. I "fixed" it by making the test a not if for now. I said I'd put it here in case anyone else came searching for the same idea.

```
#if (!$HEADER_COMMENTS)
//
// Created by $USER_NAME on ${DATE}.
#if ($ORGANIZATION_NAME && $ORGANIZATION_NAME != "")
// Copyright (c) $YEAR ${ORGANIZATION_NAME}#if (!$ORGANIZATION_NAME.endsWith(".")).#end All rights reserved.
#end
//
#end
```

Comment: Nice. You can also use Apache Velocity template comments (`#* ... *#`) to comment out the header. https://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#comments